# Receiving a "String index out of range: 0" when trying to convert a PDF in the IBM Document Conversion service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, document-conversion

I am trying to convert a document using IBM's Document Conversion service. It is a basic PDF, 116 pages,1.1MB file.  Nothing special about it that I can see, but the DC service returns the error "**String index out of range: 0**" when I try to convert it.  FWIW, the document is the *IBM Backup and Restore Manager for z/VM User's Guide*. I have converted many other PDFs with no problems, but this one and two others are giving me this error.

Can anyone give me a clue to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share a link to the PDF that exhibits the error? I was able to convert the **IBM Backup and Restore Manager for z/VM User's Guide** from [this link](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/stormgmt/zvm/backup/BackupRestoreUserGuideSC18952309.pdf) without a problem.

Comment: The document I am trying to convert is release 3, the one behind your link is release 2, so that may be a clue.  You can try the release 3 one by going to https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhcxog4qdkiygby/SC18-9523-13.pdf?dl=0

Comment: David, I was able to reproduce the problem with version 3 of the PDF. We have fixed the issue and it will be included in the next release of the service.

Comment: Awesome! Not to be greedy, but I have some other docs that give different errors, such as {"code":400,"error":"(No error details available.)"} and {"code": 400,"error": "Value for parameter 'id' was out of bounds"} when I run them either using my code or the demo at https://document-conversion-demo.mybluemix.net/. Do you think that this fix will take care of those errors as well?  Can I send you a list?

Comment: David, those look like different issues. You can send me the docs and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took so long to respond.  I have placed a zip file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j4jna79g2zp06q/problemDocs.zip?dl=0 for you.  The readme.txt file contained within gives all of the information that I have about the conversion failure for these documents.  Please respond here when you retrieve the file so I can delete the zip and free up my limited dropbox space.

Comment: I have created an issue internally to look into those problematic documents. I have uploaded the zip file, so feel free to remove it from your dropbox.